# Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular/cli/utilities/find-up'

Tags: angular, angular-material, angularjs-directive

I Upgraded angular microfrontened from 8 to 14.After serving getting error as Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular/cli/utilities/find-up'

utilities are removed from cli on angular 14. Even after the upgraded and installing node modules they are asking this.

below angular.json
`{ "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json", "version": 1, "newProjectRoot": "projects", "projects": { "vitrana": { "projectType": "application", "schematics": { "@schematics/angular:component": { "style": "scss" } }, "root": "", "sourceRoot": "src", "prefix": "app", "architect": { "build": { "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser", "options": { "outputPath": "output/hilit", "index": "src/index.html", "main": "src/main.single-spa.ts", "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts", "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json", "aot": false, "assets": [ "src/favicon.ico", "src/assets", { "glob": "**/*", "input": "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/", "output": "/assets/" } ], "stylePreprocessorOptions": { "includePaths": [ "./src/scss/declarations/colors.scss" ] }, "styles": [ "./src/scss/styles.scss" ], "scripts": [ "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js", ], "customWebpackConfig": { "path": "./extra-webpack.config.js", "libraryName": "vitrana", "libraryTarget": "umd" } }, "configurations": { "production": { "fileReplacements": [ { "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts", "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts" } ], "optimization": true, "sourceMap": false, "extractCss": false, "namedChunks": false, "aot": true, "extractLicenses": true, "vendorChunk": false, "buildOptimizer": true, "budgets": [ { "type": "initial", "maximumWarning": "2mb", "maximumError": "7mb" }, { "type": "anyComponentStyle", "maximumWarning": "6kb", "maximumError": "10kb" } ] } } }, "serve": { "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server", "options": { "browserTarget": "vitrana:build", "aot": true }, "configurations": { "production": { "browserTarget": "vitrana:build:production" } } }, "extract-i18n": { "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n", "options": { "browserTarget": "vitrana:build" } }, "test": { "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma", "options": { "main": "src/test.ts", "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts", "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json", "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js", "assets": [ "src/favicon.ico", "src/assets" ], "styles": [ "src/styles.scss" ], "scripts": [] } }, "e2e": { "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor", "options": { "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js", "devServerTarget": "vitrana:serve" }, "configurations": { "production": { "devServerTarget": "vitrana:serve:production" } } } } } } }`

Comment: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.